# Prices based on quarter returned

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using the table below to get pricing for an individual using [excel](/questions/tagged/excel). I am using the formula below to see what today's date is and get the month and it give the quarter that the month is in. This information is on sheet one. This formula,

```
=ROUNDUP(MONTH(TODAY())/3,0)
```

, returns what Quarter we are in. I would like to know if I could match the number retuned can match the number above the month range and pick the price. so this would be changed automatically.

```
    Table 1
    To      | From |Price
    sudtent | ac   | get pricr 
    sudtent | MC   | get pricr

        Table 2
                              |           2     |        3       |       4     |  1 
                    TO  | FROM|   April to June |   July to Sept |  Oct to Dec |Jan to March        
                Student | AC  |          130    |       97.50    |     65.00   |  162.50
                Student | MC  |      180        |     135.00     |   90.00     |   225.00
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the **quarter** (e.g. ³⁄₁₂ of a year) you would divide by **4**, not 3.

```
=ROUNDUP(MONTH(TODAY())/4, 0)
'alternate
=CEILING(MONTH(TODAY())/4, 1)
```

An [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a)/[MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) function pair can provide the return from your pricing data matrix if you supply both the *row_number* and *column_number* parameters of the INDEX lookup.

In C3 as,

```
=INDEX(D$9:G$99, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($1:$91)/((B$9:B$99=A3)*(C$9:C$99=B3)), 1), MATCH(CEILING(MONTH(TODAY())/4, 1), $D$7:$G$7, 0))
```

Fill down as necessary.

[image: execl_student_prices]